# How to use java built-in exception in Thrift IDL

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

I'd like to throws some java built-in exception such IOException in the Thrift IDL.

like this:

service B{
     void removeLease() throws (1:ioexception e),
}

however, the Thrift compiler warns that ioexception doesn't be defined.

Comment: It will become interesting when a Client connects which is not written in Java. What can he do with the payload Java exception other than just ignore it? Would that be a blocker?

Answer (score 3):

Every java exception is serializable, so it's possible to wrap it into thrift exception.

Thrift code:

```
exception SerializedException
{
    1: required binary payload
}

service MyService
{
    int method(1: required string param) throws (1: SerializedException serializedException);
}
```

Java server code:

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService.Iface {
    int method(String param) throws SerializedException {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            new ObjectOutputStream(os).writeObject(ex);
            throw new SerializedException(os.toByteArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Java client code:

```
try {
    int r = myService.method("param");
} catch (SerializedException ex) {
    Exception nested = <Deserialize ex.payload via ByteArrayInputStream>
    ...
}
```

So, the client gets full exception together with stacktrace, etc. We use this approach is several projects, it works for sure.

Comment: Your Java server code, at the very least, isn't right for Java 6 (maybe it's Java 7, I'm not sure).

Comment: If you want to still have some non-Java clients, which won't be able to deserialize the exception without _a lot_ of extra work, it can be combined with at least exposing exception class name and/or message in the `SerializedException`.

Answer (score 0):

Thrift IDL is language agnostic.You cannot use built-in exceptions(like IOException in this case)
You can define and use your own "ioexception"

```
exception ioexception
{
 1:string msg,
}
```

Comment: I am still quite doubted about this "ioexception". For I've generated related java-code for this "ioexception", and found there are some differences between this "ioexception" and the java built-in IOException. For example, IOException has more constructors than this one, which I am worry about, for there may be some situations using these missing Constructors. Thank you!